# In scrapy 1.3, what is the difference between a yield request and a return request?

Tags: scrapy

It seems they are providing the same function, ultimately returning a dict or item through a pipeline or feed.  Is there a reason I would use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In contrast to "return", "yield" doesn't exit the function and continues
with the your for-loop. If you use "return", your for-loop will finish after the first iteration.

For more information: 
[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855)